# Certain mailto: links working, the rest on the page don't

Tags: html, mailto

I'm having one hell of a head scratcher here. I've got 7 mailto: links on a webpage. 3 work, the rest don't. What I mean is that when I hover over the ones that work, they change colour like they should on the :hover and I can click them and they open up my mail client.

Now the rest of them, just show up as normal text, and are not clickable links at all, despite the markup explicity stating them as `<a href="mailto:the@address">blahblahblah</a>`.

I've never had this happen before, and I really confused. I've looked over my markup to see if anything was breaking the rest of markup, but it's all *exactly* the same.

The first four peoples mailto: links do *not* work, whereas the bottom 3 people's do work.

I'm so confused, and desperate for help on this, as I cannot fathom why this is happening!

I've googled a lot, and everyone else's issues refer back to extensions/addons installed, and they have *no* mailto: links working, whereas I have 3 out of 7 working on a page..

Here is the markup:

```
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Meet our core team.</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;">They oversee our network of multi-lingual account managers, CRM wizards, researchers, writers and translators to deliver for clients.</p>

<div id="team_photo_img_container">

<div id="andi_catt" class="team_photo">
    <img id="andiCatt" class="alignleft wp-image-46 size-large" title="Andi Catt" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/polaroid_AC.jpg" alt="Andi Catt 5" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
    <div  class="team_photo_copy">

        <hr />

        Andi Catt, Managing Director

        Andi founded The Call Business in 2011 after a 30-year career in sales and telemarketing, which has included an award from the Direct Marketing Association. Andi is responsible for the strategic direction of the company, for business development and for managing mystery shopping and client training programmes.

        <span>Email: <a href="mailto:andi@business.com">andi@business.com</a></span>

    </div>

</div>

<div id="team_photo_img_container">

<div id="rachel_staddon" class="team_photo">
    <img class="alignleft wp-image-52 size-large" title="Rachel Staddon" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/polaroid_RS.jpg" alt="Rachel Staddon 2" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
    <div class="team_photo_copy">

        <hr />

        Rachel Staddon, Client Services Director

        Having moved from media sales to client services six years ago, Rachel joined us earlier this year and is responsible for customer service and quality control. She oversees our customer relationships and ensures we exceed client expectations.

        <span>Email: <a href="mailto: rachel@business.com">rachel@business.com</a></span>

    </div>

<div id="sarah_read" class="team_photo">
    <img class="alignleft wp-image-53 size-large" title="Sarah Read" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/polaroid_SR.jpg" alt="Sarah Read 1" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
    <div class="team_photo_copy">

        <hr />

        Sarah Read, Operations Manager

        Sarah’s background as a legal secretary and HR administrator stands her in good stead. She is the glue that holds us together, overseeing contracts, accounts, recruitment and HR.

        <span>Email: <a href="mailto:sarah@business.com">sarah@business.com</a></span>

    </div>

<div id="melanie_clarke" class="team_photo">
    <img class="alignleft wp-image-51 size-large" title="Melanie Clarke" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/polaroid_MC.jpg" alt="Melanie Clarke 1" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
    <div class="team_photo_copy">

        <hr />

        Melanie Clarke, Account Director

        Melanie has a background in account management and business development within the creative and print industries. As well as managing our largest account on a day-to-day basis, she is our advisor on direct marketing and one of our event marketing specialists.

        <span>Email: <a href="mailto:melanie@business.com">melanie@business.com</a></span>

    </div>

</div>


<div id="team_photo_img_container">

<div id="claire_grant" class="team_photo">
    <img class="alignleft wp-image-84 size-large" title="Claire Grant" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/polaroid_CG.jpg" alt="Claire Grant 1" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
    <div class="team_photo_copy">

        <hr />

        Claire Grant, Senior Account Manager

        Claire primarily works with clients who want to set up in-house telemarketing operations. Having previously managed the branch of a recruitment agency, she provides guidance and support on team structure and the recruitment process. Claire also works with Sarah on the recruitment of our own telemarketers.

        <span>Email: <a href="mailto:claire@business.com">claire@business.com</a></span>

    </div>

<div id="emily_pitt" class="team_photo">
    <img class="alignleft wp-image-49 size-large" title="Emily Jane Pitt" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/polaroid_EJP.jpg" alt="Emily Jane Pitt 1" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
    <div class="team_photo_copy">

        <hr />

        Emily Pitt, Senior Account Manager

        Emily has spent many years working in the creative and events industries, having worked for D&amp;AD, the Science Museum and a number of prestigious venues in London. Emily manages several of our accounts and provides expertise to clients interested in hosting events.

        <span>Email: <a href="mailto:emily@business.com">emily@business.com</a></span>

    </div>

<div id="david_coates" class="team_photo">
    <img class="alignleft wp-image-48 size-large" title="David Coates" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/polaroid_DC.jpg" alt="David Coates 3" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
    <div class="team_photo_copy">

        <hr />

        David Coates, Account Manager

        David - always know as DC - was a professional sportsman before joining our team. He supports our largest client with calls to English-speaking companies in North America and the Far East.

        <span>Email: <a href="mailto:dc@business.com">dc@business.com</a></span>

    </div>

</div>

<h3>Making the calls</h3>
We have a rapidly expanding team of experienced, friendly, engaging account managers and telemarketers who make calls for our clients in an ever-growing range of <a title="Multilingual" href="http://business.com/what-we-do/multilingual/">languages</a>. Unless they are truly bi or tri-lingual, our team only make calls in their native language.
```

Comment: Looks absolutely fine to me.  Can you post a screenshot of the output you're getting?

Comment: Do you have any other scripts, CSS, etc. attached? The HTML seems fine (see http://jsfiddle.net/80qocfwL/)

Comment: One other thing i would add, is you never want to have multiple tags with the same ID (your photo containers all have the same ID: "team_photo_img_container"). If you need to affect them all, use a class that they can share, not an ID. This shouldn't affect your mailto links but it is definitely an issue.

Comment: Also on line 42, the mailto link for rachel@business.com has a space in the href attribute, which is illegal.

Comment: maybe `"` is problem. check whole file for `"`

Comment: Thank you for all your inputs guys, I took into consideration Calvins reply, changed it to a class instead of an id. That didn't make it work, but in the end, I changed the markup so there was only one 'team_photo_img_container' and magically.. it all worked.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I changed my markup to this:

```
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Meet our core team.</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;">They oversee our network of multi-lingual account managers, CRM wizards, researchers, writers and translators to deliver for clients.</p>

<div class="team_photo_img_container">

<div id="andi_catt" class="team_photo">
    <img id="andiCatt" class="alignleft wp-image-46 size-large" title="Andi Catt" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/polaroid_AC.jpg" alt="Andi Catt 5" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
    <div  class="team_photo_copy">

        <hr />

        Andi Catt, Managing Director

        Andi founded The Call Business in 2011 after a 30-year career in sales and telemarketing, which has included an award from the Direct Marketing Association. Andi is responsible for the strategic direction of the company, for business development and for managing mystery shopping and client training programmes.

        <span>Email: <a href="mailto:andi@business.com">andi@business.com</a></span>

    </div>





<div id="rachel_staddon" class="team_photo">
    <img class="alignleft wp-image-52 size-large" title="Rachel Staddon" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/polaroid_RS.jpg" alt="Rachel Staddon 2" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
    <div class="team_photo_copy">

        <hr />

        Rachel Staddon, Client Services Director

        Having moved from media sales to client services six years ago, Rachel joined us earlier this year and is responsible for customer service and quality control. She oversees our customer relationships and ensures we exceed client expectations.

        <span>Email: <a href="mailto:rachel@business.com">rachel@business.com</a></span>

    </div>

<div id="sarah_read" class="team_photo">
    <img class="alignleft wp-image-53 size-large" title="Sarah Read" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/polaroid_SR.jpg" alt="Sarah Read 1" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
    <div class="team_photo_copy">

        <hr />

        Sarah Read, Operations Manager

        Sarah’s background as a legal secretary and HR administrator stands her in good stead. She is the glue that holds us together, overseeing contracts, accounts, recruitment and HR.

        <span>Email: <a href="mailto:sarah@business.com">sarah@business.com</a></span>

    </div>

<div id="melanie_clarke" class="team_photo">
    <img class="alignleft wp-image-51 size-large" title="Melanie Clarke" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/polaroid_MC.jpg" alt="Melanie Clarke 1" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
    <div class="team_photo_copy">

        <hr />

        Melanie Clarke, Account Director

        Melanie has a background in account management and business development within the creative and print industries. As well as managing our largest account on a day-to-day basis, she is our advisor on direct marketing and one of our event marketing specialists.

        <span>Email: <a href="mailto:melanie@business.com">melanie@business.com</a></span>

    </div>

<div id="claire_grant" class="team_photo">
    <img class="alignleft wp-image-84 size-large" title="Claire Grant" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/polaroid_CG.jpg" alt="Claire Grant 1" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
    <div class="team_photo_copy">

        <hr />

        Claire Grant, Senior Account Manager

        Claire primarily works with clients who want to set up in-house telemarketing operations. Having previously managed the branch of a recruitment agency, she provides guidance and support on team structure and the recruitment process. Claire also works with Sarah on the recruitment of our own telemarketers.

        <span>Email: <a href="mailto:claire@business.com">claire@business.com</a></span>

    </div>

<div id="emily_pitt" class="team_photo">
    <img class="alignleft wp-image-49 size-large" title="Emily Jane Pitt" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/polaroid_EJP.jpg" alt="Emily Jane Pitt 1" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
    <div class="team_photo_copy">

        <hr />

        Emily Pitt, Senior Account Manager

        Emily has spent many years working in the creative and events industries, having worked for D&amp;AD, the Science Museum and a number of prestigious venues in London. Emily manages several of our accounts and provides expertise to clients interested in hosting events.

        <span>Email: <a href="mailto:emily@business.com">emily@business.com</a></span>

    </div>

<div id="david_coates" class="team_photo">
    <img class="alignleft wp-image-48 size-large" title="David Coates" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/polaroid_DC.jpg" alt="David Coates 3" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
    <div class="team_photo_copy">

        <hr />

        David Coates, Account Manager

        David - always know as DC - was a professional sportsman before joining our team. He supports our largest client with calls to English-speaking companies in North America and the Far East.

        <span>Email: <a href="mailto:dc@business.com">dc@business.com</a></span>

    </div>

</div>

<h3>Making the calls</h3>
We have a rapidly expanding team of experienced, friendly, engaging account managers and telemarketers who make calls for our clients in an ever-growing range of <a title="Multilingual" href="http://business.com/what-we-do/multilingual/">languages</a>. Unless they are truly bi or tri-lingual, our team only make calls in their native language.
```

So by simply removing the other two "team_photo_img_container" elements, it all worked, and I must say, looks a lot better too.

Sorry to be such a nuisance guys, I really appreciate all the input!

Keep on rockin'!

Comment: Happy to hear it. And thanks for answering your own question and not just abandoning the thread once it was working :)